# optimising Arduino This Code

Tags: arduino

I crated a Light Sensor so When it's dark outside it will turn on the light.
So i connected for now Photo Sensitive sensor and a Button to calibrate.
I wanted to know if you have any Tips How To optimise this gigantic Code...
I'm sure there is where because I'm new in Arduino.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

const int RED_Pin = 9;
const int GREEN_Pin = 10;
const int BLUE_Pin = 11;
const int PHOTO_sense = 0;
const int Button = 12;
int RoomLight;
int Sensor;

LiquidCrystal lcd(7,6,5,4,3,2);

void setup()
{


  lcd.begin(16,2);
  lcd.clear();
 pinMode(RED_Pin,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(GREEN_Pin,OUTPUT);
 pinMode(BLUE_Pin,OUTPUT); 
 pinMode(Button,INPUT);
 Serial.begin(9600);
 sync();
 Serial.print(Button);
}


void loop(){
  Sensor = analogRead(PHOTO_sense);
  Sensor = map(Sensor,0,1023,0,255);
  Sensor = constrain(Sensor,0,255);
  if(Sensor < RoomLight-5){
   digitalWrite(RED_Pin,LOW);
   digitalWrite(GREEN_Pin,HIGH);
  }else{
   digitalWrite(GREEN_Pin,LOW);
   digitalWrite(RED_Pin,HIGH);
  }
  delay(500);
  if(digitalRead(Button)==0){ //Buton Is Pressed so We Need to Sync
    delay(2000);
      if(digitalRead(Button) == 0){
          sync();
      }
    delay(2500);
  }
}

int sync(){
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Calibriting");
  int compre [4];
  int Sum=0;
  for (int Loop = 4;Loop>0;Loop--){
  lcd.print(".");
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(BLUE_Pin,HIGH);
  compre[Loop] =  analogRead(PHOTO_sense);
  delay(500); 
  digitalWrite(BLUE_Pin,LOW);

  Sum=Sum+compre[Loop];
  }
    RoomLight = Sum/4;    
    RoomLight = map(RoomLight,0,1023,0,255);
    RoomLight = constrain(RoomLight,0,255);    
    lcd.clear();

    lcd.print("done Calibration");
    delay(2500);
 return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On a quick glance the first suggestion can be:

Add a function to do repetitive work

I see you at least twice to the same action

```
Sensor = map(Sensor,0,1023,0,255);
Sensor = constrain(Sensor,0,255);
RoomLight = map(RoomLight,0,1023,0,255);
RoomLight = constrain(RoomLight,0,255);
```

you can add a function like this

```
int recalc_light(input)
{
    retVal = map(input, 0, 1023, 0, 255);
    return constrain(retVal, 0, 255);
}
```

and then call it this way:

```
Sensor = recalc_light(analogRead(PHOTO_sense));
RoomLight = recalc_light(Sum/4);
```

secondly I see your function int sync() always returns a 0

you could always rewrite it as below:

```
void sync()
{
    lcd.clear();
    ...
    ...
    lcd.print("done Calibration");
    delay(2500);
}
```

A third comment may be to write consistently, by example always start a { or a } on a new line. For a clear overview (but this is personal flavor) you can as I did above make sure it is the only character on a line. 
Also keep mind of identation, after each '{' add some extra 2 or 4 spaces.

In this way your code will look nicer.

by example:

```
void sync()
{
     lcd.clear();
     lcd.print("Calibriting");
     int compre [4];
     int Sum=0;
     for (int Loop = 4;Loop>0;Loop--)
     {
          lcd.print(".");
          delay(500);
          digitalWrite(BLUE_Pin,HIGH);
          compre[Loop] =  analogRead(PHOTO_sense);
          delay(500);
          digitalWrite(BLUE_Pin,LOW);
          Sum=Sum+compre[Loop];
     }
     RoomLight = recalc_light(Sum/4);    
     lcd.clear();
     lcd.print("done Calibration");
     delay(2500);
```

}

Comment: you could also do some research on [interrupts](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Interrupts)
with these interrupts you can handle the detection of the button press without having to wait for 500 ms